# Bricked flash drive with no size

Tags: usb-drive

I have a bricked usb stick Kingston DT101 G2. I tried the solutions I found on the net without success. The problem seems to be that the capacity is reported as 0 (and not *less than actual* as in other questions). (Although I don't know a command to explicitly query the capacity.)

Sticking it in, `/dev/sdd` appears but `/dec/sdd1` does not appear.

`gparted`/`parted`/`fdisk` don't recognize it. e.g.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdd: No such file or directory
```

---

```
$ sudo dd count=1 bs=512 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd && sync
dd: error writing '/dev/sdd': No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000316047 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

---

```
$ ls -l /dev/sdd
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 48 Jan 30 13:45 /dev/sdd`
```

---

```
$ sudo xxd -l 10 /dev/sdd
$
```

<sub><sup>(i.e. nothing)</sup></sub>

```
$ sudo smartctl -i -d scsi /dev/sdd
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-109-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               GENERIC
Product:              USB Mass Storage
Revision:             1.00
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=4 offset=4 bd_len=0
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=4 offset=4 bd_len=0
Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.`
```

[Edit]

- `sudo lsblk`: no mention of sdd.

Output of `lsusb -v` (relevant portion only) Note that it reports 2GB instead of the actual 16GB.

```
Bus 001 Device 022: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0930 Toshiba Corp.
  idProduct          0x6544 TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              200mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
    bInterval             255
      Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
    bInterval             255
```

Comment: For what even a top-end flash drive costs, unless there's critical data that exists only on that drive, likely the best way to "fix" this is to buy another one.

Comment: When `sudo dd count=1 bs=512 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd && sync` fails to write, and the tips in the list at the following link does not help, your drive is broken beyond repair. *Try according to the tips in the list* before giving up, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Comment: A common 4GB flash drive (twice this capacity) is around $5 new.  How much work is it worth to fix this one?

Comment: Followed the list. Edited the question to add output of lsusb. From point 2 on the list I can only arrive at 'gridlocked', although the stick is almost new.

Comment: If you tried in another computer, with another operating system etc, and still no luck, I think your drive is broken beyond repair. This can happen 'any time' if you have bad luck. If it is almost new, and you have kept the receipt, maybe you can get it replaced with a new one.

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve?